# Reduce horizontal gap between legend and pie chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

How to reduce the gab between the pie chart and legend. Following is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure*}[h]
\centering      
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
every node/.style={align=center},
pin distance=9mm,
font={\small},
scale=0.65
]
\pie[
/tikz/every pin/.style={align=center},
every only number node/.style={text=white},
text=legend,
rotate=240,
explode=0.2,    
] {33/{2020}, 24/{2019}, 27/{2018}, 12/{2017}, 2/{2016}, 2/{2015}}      
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is much work to go through, the technique I found to work is to superimpose pies, with each superimposition providing a needed part of the final result.  Here, I superimpose 3 pies in the revised figure.  The first adjusts the legend by plotting a smaller pie (which is later covered up).  The second fixes another problem with the OP's plot, which is that small slice percentages overlap and bleed past the side of their slice, so I move the label to the outside.  The third pie replots those slices that can support having their percent on top of the slice itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering      
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
every node/.style={align=center},
pin distance=9mm,
font={\small},
scale=0.65
]
\pie[
/tikz/every pin/.style={align=center},
every only number node/.style={text=white},
text=legend,
rotate=240,
explode=0.2,    
] {33/{2020}, 24/{2019}, 27/{2018}, 12/{2017}, 2/{2016}, 2/{2015}}      
\end{tikzpicture}  
\caption{Original} 
\end{figure*}

  \begin{figure*}[h]
\centering      
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
every node/.style={align=center},
pin distance=9mm,
font={\small},
scale=0.65
]
\pie[
/tikz/every pin/.style={align=center},
every only number node/.style={text=white},
text=legend, 
radius=2.3, % PIE SIZE WILL SHIFT THE LEGEND,
hide number, % DON'T WANT 2% NUMBERS VISIBLE ON PIE
rotate=240,
explode=0.2,    
] {33/{2020}, 24/{2019}, 27/{2018}, 12/{2017}, 2/{2016}, 2/{2015}}   
%
\pie[
/tikz/every pin/.style={align=center}, 
every only number node/.style={text=white},
rotate=225.6,%  PUT 2% SLICES WHERE THEY BELONG, explode REQUIRES TWEAK 
hide number,% DON'T ACTUALLY PRINT NUMBERS ON PIE
explode=0.2,    
] {0/,0/,0/,0/, % ZEROS REQUIRED TO GET SLICE COLORS RIGHT
  2/2\%, 2/\raisebox{-10pt}{\rlap{2\%}~~}% PLOT % AS LABEL, ADJUST
}      
%
\pie[
/tikz/every pin/.style={align=center},
every only number node/.style={text=white},
rotate=240,
explode=0.2,    
] {33/, 24/, 27/, 12/}  % ONLY PLOT SLICES WHERE I WANT NUMBERS    
\end{tikzpicture}   
\caption{Revised}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

A command `\WCtest` is defined of which the output depends on whether the percentage is larger than 10. This command is used in the keys `data` and `wheel data`. Here, the percentage is obtained with `\WCperc`.

The slices are shifted using the key `explode`.

The legend is determined by the key `legend`. This is a `tabular` which is placed in a `\node`. The rows are determined by the key `legend row`. The result of all rows can be obtained with `\WClegend`.

The macro `\WClistcolors` refers to items in the list given to the key `WClistcolors`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\WCtest#1#2{%
  \pgfmathparse{\WCpercentage>10?"#1":"#2"}%
  \pgfmathresult%
}
\wheelchart[
  counterclockwise,
  data=\WCtest{}{\WCperc},
  explode,
  legend row={\tikz\fill[\WClistcolors,draw=black] (0,0) rectangle (0.3,0.3); & \WCvarB},
  legend={
    \node[anchor=west] at (3.5,0) {%
      \begin{tabular}{l@{ }l}%
      \WClegend%
      \end{tabular}%
    };
  },
  pie,
  slices style={\WClistcolors,draw=black},
  start angle=240,
  WClistcolors={blue!60,cyan!60,yellow!60,orange!60,red!60,blue!60!cyan!60,cyan!60!yellow!60,red!60!cyan!60,red!60!blue!60,orange!60!cyan!60},
  wheel data=\WCtest{\WCperc}{}
]{%
  33/2020,
  24/2019,
  27/2018,
  12/2017,
  2/2016,
  2/2015%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```